# Handlebars Missing helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, helper, handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement my own helper for Handlerbars but i cannot figure out where i need to register it so I can access it inside my template.
I always get Missing helper: "abcde"

I've checked many of the same questions on here having the same issue but with no success.

Here's my app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var expresshandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', expresshandlebars({ defaultLayout: 'main', layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts') }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

handlebars.registerHelper('abcde',
  function (str) {
    return str;
  }
);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../site')));

app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here's how i use the template inside my main.handlebars layout file:

```
<a href="/" class="item">{{abcde "test"}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this technique?  From here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance. 
    helpers: {
        foo: function () { return 'FOO!'; },
        bar: function () { return 'BAR!'; }
    }
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Either way, I would focus on setting the helper on your expresshandlebars, and not your handlebars variable.